# Replace disk electronics in HDD Password Protected hard drives

Tags: hard-drive, passwords, data-recovery

I have HDD password protected hard drive (Seagate ST320LT007) which dies recently, most probably because of damaged electronics.

I would like to buy new one and replace demaged electronic with workingone from new disk.

I've read in a couple of places ([here](https://superuser.com/questions/69981/free-utility-to-recover-or-remove-laptop-hard-disk-password) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/61725/bios-hard-drive-password-security)) that password is stored in hard drive firmware and also somewhere on the disk itself and it is possible to unlock such hard drive with dedicated software.

But what in case when I know the password, but electronic has been demaged and it has been then replaced with new-one? Are there any chances to succesfuly recover/unlock such disk?

Comment: How are you planning on fixing the HD and why do think it's the electronics? Most HD are not easily repairable and most HD failures are because of platter issues.

Comment: I can guarantee you that password is not stored in the firmware of the hdd since that would require the firmware be used as a kind of stoarage and that would be a horrible idea.

Comment: @BradPatton I think it's electronics, because before the disk eventually dies, I could read the data in Windows 7 Safe Mode. Also Windows 7 loads correctly, but then, after log in, it suddently stops to respond. Then a day after disk dies and it was even unable to start and was not recognized by BIOS.

Comment: @Ramhound I've read for example [in this thread](http://superuser.com/questions/61725/bios-hard-drive-password-security): "HDD password defined as part of the ATA specifications" so I thought that HD password is stored somewhere in Electronics, so "firmware" is probably not precise enought.

Answer (score 1):

Have an expert (data recovery company? official maintenance outfit for Seagate?) take a look. If that is too expensive, the data isn't really worth anything to you. Take the drive to the nearest electronics junk drop for recycling.

Comment: Of course if anythyning else will fail then I will get in touch with Data Recovery Company, but in the first place I think it's nothing wrong to ask others for their advice/opinion in similar cases.

Comment: If you start messing with it, chances are that you break it more. Disks going bad normally have an _extremely_ limited life left...

Comment: I would like only to know whether replacement of the electronics has any sense. I will not do anything more with disk instead of replacement of electronic. Maybe this is enogh to bring the disk back to life.