# How to set SATA password in AMI BIOS 0307?

Tags: ssd, motherboard, bios, sata

How to set SATA password in AMI BIOS 0307? I can't find any possible option to do that, there is only supervisor and user password in Boot->security section. I have ocz agility 3 with sandforce controller. Mobo is m4a88t-v

Comment: What is a SATA password?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg He is probably asking about [HDD BIOS Password.](http://superuser.com/q/61725/79358)

Comment: @OliverSalzburg It is SATA level disk lock. Password is stored on the device, not in BIOS. In self encrypted SSDs it is great solution however encryption keys are randomly generated and not connected with password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately desktop mobos have no such feature. It is only possible in laptops.