# How to remove HDD password (knowing the password) with another machine?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, passwords

### Background

I have a hard drive with HDD password set from Dell XPS 15 (L502x) laptop that the screen cable has been burned, so I tried to connect the hard drive to another TOSHIBA Satellite laptop and when it prompt for HDD password, I type it and it said that the password is incorrect when I am sure the correctness of the password typed, so I tried with another Dell XPS M1530 and it said the same.

### Question

I do not know whether the HDD password is machine-specific. How can I access the content, or remove the HDD password with another laptop?

Comment: I found a bit similar question go through this : http://superuser.com/questions/61725/bios-hard-drive-password-security/61751#61751  Because all I found was third party solutions.

Comment: Attach an external monitor or your TV.  From the picture I saw it has an HDMI port.

Comment: @MusselmanLLC I tried to use the Mini DisplayPort and HDMI port on the Dell XPS 15 (L502x), the machine start, but it did not show anything,, that is why I am using another laptop.

Comment: @selah1936 Yeah I tried to find solutions, but their answer is not applicable because I know the password. I just wanted to access it with another laptop.

Comment: Ok.. No issues. I found one article which might help you. Please go through it: http://www.wikihow.com/Recover-Data-from-the-Hard-Drive-of-a-Dead-Laptop